# Why is this date not processing correctly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, int

I have this code:

```
currentMinuteInt = [[cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit 
                           fromDate:tuesdayAlarmTime] minute];
```

which should have outputted '15', but instead outputted '-2147483587'. I recognise this weird sort of number being shown sometimes in relation to dates, but I can't figure out why it's happening here.

The code i have for working out the hour is:

```
hours = [[cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now] hour];
```

and that works correctly. tuesdayAlarmTime is a full length date, and the minute part of it is '15'.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be

```
currentMinuteInt = [[cal components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:tuesdayAlarmTime] minute];
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

With `[cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:tuesdayAlarmTime]`, your `NSDateComponents` object only contains an hour value, nothing else. Instead, you must use:

```
[cal components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:tuesdayAlarmTime]
```